# How do you save the value of a textbox on the server with php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I tried to save the elements in a textbox to a text file on the server by using php. I've searched for solutions but none of them worked yet. This is a snippet of my HTML and JS part:

```
<input type="search" id="textinput" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendText() {
    var dataset = { "value": document.getElementById('textinput').value };
    console.log(dataset);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sendText.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataset,
        success: function() {
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
}
</script>
<button type="submit" id="button" onclick="sendText()">Send</button>
```

and this is the php:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('chat.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['value']);
?>
```

If someone could help me there I would be thankful!

Comment: what is the issue? $_POST['value']  gives error, change in ajax data: {'value':dataset},

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Save it when the user submits a form?

Comment: Yes. When the user clicks on the send button, it should save the textbox value to the file.

Comment: What happens when u submit? Also, have you tried debugging? Like dumping $_POST to see if anything is sent?     Note: I don't know if.it will solve it, but I usually put my script after the form.